# Is it possible to make the Parity software sync faster?

Tags: parity

I start Parity software like so: `parity -j`

It takes a really long time to sync.

Is there any way to make it sync faster?

Answer (score 25):

First of all, you can increase the cache size to speed up block processing,  for example to 1GB with `--cache-size 1024`. Increase it even further if you have more memory available. I'm using `4096`.

If you either have a hard drive, or a solid state disk, optimize the database compaction for each type with `--db-compaction hdd` or `--db-compaction ssd` respectively.

Make sure transaction tracing is off with `--tracing off`, however, this should be already the default behavior.

Use the fast pruning mode with `--pruning fast` which reduces the state size kept in the client. Recently, this is also the default for parity.

Make sure you sync in active mode with `--mode active` which does never stop actively syncing and importing blocks.

Finally, if you need to fresh sync your chain, do it in warp mode with `--warp`. This fetches the latest state and latest 30k blocks from the chain and makes your node usable within only a couple of minutes.

In one line:

```
parity --mode active --tracing off --pruning fast --db-compaction ssd --cache-size 1024
```

Comment: I can test your one-liner but how do I initiate a fresh sync then?

Comment: I am trying your one liner but it seems about as slow as the result I get with just -warp. Seems very slow around block #2427470 and the blocks before and after that. I need to know if I should just continue or start over from the beginning with the one liner?

Comment: Answering my own question: deleting the whole .parity folder seems to do the trick. Just remember to backup the keys first if anyone else is reading this.

Comment: Removing the  `~/.parity/906a34e69aec8c0d`` subfolder is sufficient.

Comment: `--warp` is on by default. Explicitly defining the flag gives error `Found argument '--warp' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context`. So now there is no need to include `--warp` in the command.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the `--warp` flag is what you're looking for, as detailed on their [wiki](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Warp-Sync) and announced on their [blog](https://blog.ethcore.io/announcing-parity-1-4/).

```
parity --warp
```

Comment: Is it necessary to start over from scratch or can I start with --warp when I already have 70% of the blockchain downloaded through parity -j?

Comment: Deleting the blockchain and resyncing with --warp is faster than waiting for the rest of the 30%.

Comment: I did not see much speed-up. Please note that I am using 1 GiB RAM to download my own private chain. @Richard Horrocks

Answer (score 2):

**Use this unless you know for sure you need more than what the light client has to offer.**

```
parity --light
```

1. Works well for and sets up a highly functional, light node(light nodes in ethereum are much more capable and safe compared to Bitcoin's)
2. Downloads a chunk of verified blocks and only syncs few blocks after.
3. If you are using a HDD, this make it possible to sync to the end as the current IO makes it (almost) impossible to sync without an SSD.

Also, running `parity --light db kill` will delete your existing chain data if you are already syncing.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my configurations that I derived from answer by Afri(5chdn) and have been using for syncing to mainnet. If not anyone else, it shall help me later ;)

> config.toml

```
[parity]
mode = "active"
base_path = "$HOME/parityDatadir"

[footprint]
tracing = "off"
pruning = "fast"
db_compaction = "ssd"
cache_size = 4096

[network]
port = 30303
min_peers = 50
max_peers = 100
```

> startParityMainnet.sh

`nohup parity --config config.toml --unsafe-expose &`