# Parity: Is it possible to copy-paste/migrate Parity database into new node instead of syncing? Sync operation is very slow on 1 GiB RAM

Tags: parity

I am using Amazon Web Services (AWS)'s 1 GiB RAM free instance. I have private Ethereum network, which has around 1,500,000 blocks, but most blocks are empty. There is not much transactions exist and chain is around 1 GiB size.

First I was syncing without using `--warp` flag. Based on [suggestions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/10466/4575), I used `--warp` and it get much much slower. Now it is almost 5 hours and I am still on 300,000 th block.

**The way I run parity node:**

```
parity --warp --geth --chain /home/ubuntu/EBloc/parity.json --network-id 23422 --reserved-peers /home/ubuntu/EBloc/myPrivateNetwork.txt --jsonrpc-apis web3,eth,net,parity,parity_accounts,traces,rpc,parity_set --author $COINBASE --rpccorsdomain=* --mode active --tracing off --pruning fast --db-compaction ssd --cache-size 1024
```

**[Q]** Why migh `Parity` sycn that slow? `--warp` did not make any speed-up instead it make syncing operation much slow.

**[Q]** I have up-to-date chain on my server machine. Would it be possible to copy-paste/migrate the `Parity`'s chain database (`/home/ubuntu/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum`) I already have into AWS instance, since copy-paste operation is much faster than the syncing operation?

```
ubuntu@space:~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum$ ls
chains  dapps  keys  network  signer
```

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: `--wrap` is not a parity flag :D, and yes, you can just copy-paste your `chain/` to another machine.

Comment: What is --wrap than? :) @5chdn

Comment: well `wrap` did not save the day :( It is actually not stuck but it has been 10 hours and still in around 900,000th block, originally it should not be that slow. I am using 1 GB AWS instance to create an amazon image and people could create instance with greater RAM if they want. here is the log: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/483b655d9a5f232dc2b0a765ab339d96/raw/0f8345801825d954935db753f8d18523f3f95599/parity_log @5chdn

Comment: You meant `chains/` ?: `io.parity.ethereum/chains$ ls  =>
EBloc  ethereum  ver.lock` @5chdn

Comment: I find the difference: `Parity/v1.7.0-beta-5f2cabd-20170727/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.18.0`: `97 MiB db` and `20 blk/s` ... but on some other 1 GiB RAM instance its `Parity/v1.6.4-beta-1164193-20170322/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.16.0`:  `205 MiB db` `300 blk/s`. I really don't know why :(@5chdn

Comment: Try 1.6.10. I fear there are issues with the 1.7.0 release. We couldn't locate it yet. Are both nodes and instances configured the same way? I'll ping you on Gitter to get some insights.

Comment: update: 4 hours and 700,000 block syn with 1.6.10 not sure there is that much speed up, it becomes much slower over time... @5chdn