# Ethereum Parity is stable ~800 blocks behind

Tags: parity

I can't get up-to-date with Parity.

Real blockchain height is near 9831752, 
             Parity is pushing 9830795 currently, and Qed is 9831228.

Initially downloaded blockchain using warp mode two months ago, and currently noticed that blocks number is far behind of up-to-date number.

Parity 2.7.2 Stable 
on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

I can't understand what is wrong. VPS time is correct.

```
# date --utc
Wed Apr  8 13:23:42 UTC 2020
```

Latest log records (started with `parity --no-warp -l sync=debug`):

```
2020-04-08 15:20:18  IO Worker #2 INFO import  Syncing #9830781 0xe5e1��6f92     0.20 blk/s   11.2 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  441 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   5 MiB chain 96 MiB db 48 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:20:23  IO Worker #2 INFO import  Syncing #9830782 0x922c��053e     0.20 blk/s   34.4 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  441 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   5 MiB chain 97 MiB db 48 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:20:28  IO Worker #2 INFO import  Syncing #9830782 0x922c��053e     0.00 blk/s    0.0 tx/s    0.0 Mgas/s      0+  441 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 97 MiB db 48 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:20:33  IO Worker #2 INFO import  Syncing #9830783 0xd89f��638d     0.20 blk/s   18.6 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  441 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 97 MiB db 48 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:20:38  IO Worker #2 INFO import  Syncing #9830783 0xd89f��638d     0.00 blk/s    0.0 tx/s    0.0 Mgas/s      0+  441 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 97 MiB db 48 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:20:43  IO Worker #2 INFO import  Syncing #9830784 0xfb3a��26ce     0.20 blk/s   14.4 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  441 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 97 MiB db 48 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:20:48  IO Worker #2 INFO import  Syncing #9830784 0xfb3a��26ce     0.00 blk/s    0.0 tx/s    0.0 Mgas/s      0+  441 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 97 MiB db 48 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:20:53  IO Worker #2 INFO import  Syncing #9830785 0x7258��f6cb     0.20 blk/s   19.2 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  441 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 97 MiB db 48 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:20:58  IO Worker #2 INFO import  Syncing #9830786 0xac0b��5b4e     0.20 blk/s   34.2 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  441 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 97 MiB db 48 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:21:03  IO Worker #2 INFO import  Syncing #9830786 0xac0b��5b4e     0.00 blk/s    0.0 tx/s    0.0 Mgas/s      0+  441 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 97 MiB db 48 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:21:08  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830787 0xa5a7��d296     0.20 blk/s   27.6 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 97 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:21:13  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830787 0xa5a7��d296     0.00 blk/s    0.0 tx/s    0.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 97 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:21:18  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830788 0x32c8��dc8b     0.20 blk/s   24.2 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 97 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:21:23  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830788 0x32c8��dc8b     0.00 blk/s    0.0 tx/s    0.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 97 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:21:28  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830789 0x3500��43ec     0.20 blk/s   22.4 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 97 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:21:33  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830790 0x637d��abb6     0.20 blk/s   40.0 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 96 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:21:38  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830791 0xa01d��be23     0.20 blk/s   32.0 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 97 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:21:43  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830791 0xa01d��be23     0.00 blk/s    0.0 tx/s    0.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 97 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:21:48  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830792 0xf241��a75b     0.20 blk/s   15.8 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 96 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:21:53  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830794 0x7e9d��12ec     0.40 blk/s   61.6 tx/s    3.3 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 96 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:21:58  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830794 0x7e9d��12ec     0.00 blk/s    0.0 tx/s    0.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 96 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:22:03  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830795 0xd10e��074b     0.20 blk/s   39.6 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 96 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:22:08  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830795 0xd10e��074b     0.00 blk/s    0.0 tx/s    0.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 96 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:22:13  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830796 0x4994��8722     0.20 blk/s   19.2 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 96 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:22:18  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830797 0x9ec7��86e1     0.20 blk/s   48.0 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 96 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:22:23  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830797 0x9ec7��86e1     0.00 blk/s    0.0 tx/s    0.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 96 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:22:28  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830798 0xa41d��7b0a     0.20 blk/s   40.6 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 96 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:22:33  IO Worker #3 INFO import  Syncing #9830798 0xa41d��7b0a     0.00 blk/s    0.0 tx/s    0.0 Mgas/s      0+  429 Qed  #9831228   39/50 peers   6 MiB chain 96 MiB db 47 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:22:33  IO Worker #0 DEBUG sync  Disconnected 69
2020-04-08 15:22:38  IO Worker #0 INFO import  Syncing #9830799 0xbd61��9ed0     0.20 blk/s   14.4 tx/s    2.0 Mgas/s      0+  417 Qed  #9831228   38/50 peers   6 MiB chain 96 MiB db 45 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:22:43  IO Worker #0 INFO import  Syncing #9830799 0xbd61��9ed0     0.00 blk/s    0.0 tx/s    0.0 Mgas/s      0+  417 Qed  #9831228   38/50 peers   6 MiB chain 96 MiB db 45 MiB queue 20 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 µs
2020-04-08 15:22:45  IO Worker #3 DEBUG sync  Disconnected 86
```

*UPDATE*
I am using VPS L SSD on Contabo.
Hardware specs:
800 Gb SSD
8 CPU cores
30 GB RAM

Comment: typically these problems are caused by too "bad" hardware. You need SSD to be able to sync, at least

Comment: @LauriPeltonen, my VPS surely has SSD. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top-voted answer here on [stackexchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10465/is-it-possible-to-make-the-parity-software-sync-faster?answertab=votes#tab-top) helped a lot. Now parity is downloading around 2-10 blocks per 5 seconds.

I used these arguments:

```
parity --mode active --tracing off --pruning fast --db-compaction ssd --cache-size 4096
```